# Clearfix. Где ошибка?

Tags: html, css

Не могу разобрать с clearfix. По задумке блок div3 не должен залезать на плавающие элементы. Если ставлю отдельный блок со свойством clear: both все работает.
Если делаю через псевдоэлемент (код ниже), то подпорка не срабатывает. Можете указать где ошибка?

```
    <!-- STYLE -->
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .wrapper {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: silver;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    .div1 {
        float: left;
        background-color: rgba(227,27,191,0.5);
        width: 30%;

    }

    .div2 {
        float: left;
        background-color: #A8ECFF;
        width: 40%;

    }

    .div3 {
        width: 30%;
        height: 180px;
        background-color: #50D42A;
    }
</style>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="div1">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text </div>
    <div class="div2">Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some Text of some </div>
</div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Ссылка на кодепен: http://codepen.io/Gaxak/pen/mOvvwZ

Answer (score 2):

```
.clearfix,  
.clearfix:after,  
.clearfix:before{  
   content:"";  
   display:table;  
   clear:both;  
}
```

**вот как выглядит очистка**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но не совсем понятно почему при использовании одного селектора .clearfix:before {} фикс уж не будет работать?

Comment: но вы знаете наверно , что `:before` и так же `:after` работает как правило либо с позиционированными элементами либо с плавающими , в вашем случае условия не соблюдены , то есть нету ни того ни другого , и к тому же нужно указать весь 'спектр' к чему будет применяться очистка а у вас только для `:before` т.е после какого то элемента очищается а до и сам элемент нет

Comment: "...что :before и так же :after работает как правило либо с позиционированными элементами либо с плавающими..." - вот этого честно говоря не знал. А ссылку на соус можете дать? В спецификации, что-то не нашел :(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте как вариант для следующего шага

```
    .div3 {
        width: 30%;
        height: 180px;
        background-color: #50D42A;
        margin: 200px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: silver;
    }
```